# How to fix erratic NaN values in pandas generated by column operations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some forex data [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApMvJ4RzFb-NwXngHMtadcJZyxiJ?e=i07yUt), on which I am trying to do some pandas operations.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_excel(r"History_M1.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', dtype={'high': float, 'low':float, 'open':float, 'close':float, 'hour': str})
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)
    df.set_index('time', inplace=True)                        
    df[['high','low','open','close']] = df[['high','low','open','close']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    df['hour'] = df.index.hour
    df['hl'] = (df['high'] - df['low'])*10**4
    df['oc'] = (df['close'] - df['open'])*10**4
    df['ab'] = (df['close'] - df['open']).abs()*10**4
    df['dir'] = df[['close','open']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x['close'] > x['open'] else -1, axis=1)
```

I downsampled `df` to a hourly frequency and performed some column operations.

```
    dfh = df[['volume','high','low','open','close']].resample('1H').agg({'volume': 'sum','open': 'first','high': 'max','low': 'min','close': 'last'}).ffill()
    dfh['day'] = dfh.index.weekday
    dfh['hour'] = dfh.index.hour
    dfh['hl'] = (dfh['high'] - dfh['low'])*10**4
    dfh['oc'] = (dfh['close'] - dfh['open'])*10**4
    dfh['ab'] = (dfh['close'] - df['open']).abs()*10**4
    dfh['dir'] = dfh[['close','open']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x['close'] > x['open'] else -1, axis=1)
```

The column `dfh['ab]` is giving some NaN values for no reason. How can we fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it does not work because you replaced `dfh` by `df` here

```
 dfh['ab'] = (dfh['close'] - df['open']).abs()*10**4   # should be dfh['open']
```

Also try to change this `lambda` operation

```
df['dir'] = df[['close','open']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x['close'] > x['open'] else -1, axis=1)
```

by a `numpy` operation (much faster)

```
df['dir'] = np.where(df['close'] > df['open'], 1, -1)
```